# Deep denoising Autoencoder with layerwise pretraining hidden layers loss is diverging

Tags: pytorch, autoencoder

I need to create a deep autoencoder for image denoising for an exercise, using mnist as dataset. I'm using pytorch to build the model and for the moment this is my class for the single layer autoencoder

```
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_dim, enc_dim, last_layer=True):
    super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
    self.last_layer = last_layer
    self.input_dim = input_dim
    self.enc_dim = enc_dim
    # encoder made of one linear layer that maps a vector of size input dim into a vector of size enc_dim
    self.encoder = nn.Linear(input_dim, enc_dim)
    # the decoder will reconstruct the image in the original space
    self.decoder = nn.Linear(enc_dim, input_dim)

    self.enc_activation = nn.ReLU()

    if self.last_layer:
      self.dec_act = nn.Sigmoid()
    else:
      self.dec_act = nn.ReLU()
   
  def encode(self, x):
    x = self.encoder(x)
    x = self.enc_activation(x)
    return x
  
  def decode(self, x):
    x = self.decoder(x)
    x = self.dec_act(x)
    return x

  def forward(self, x):
    x = self.encode(x)
    x = self.decode(x)
    return x
```

Now I build the deep autoencoder stacking the layer of the autoencoder in this way

```
class DeepAutoEncoder(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_layers):
    super().__init__()

    # first layer, the decoder will reconstruct the image
    self.autoencoders = [Autoencoder(input_dim, hidden_layers[0])]
    print(f"Adding autoencoder with dim {input_dim} {hidden_layers[0]}")
    input_dim = hidden_layers[0]
    hidden_layers.pop(0)

    for elem in hidden_layers:
      print(f"Adding autoencoder with dim {input_dim} {elem}")
      self.autoencoders.append(Autoencoder(input_dim, elem, False))
      input_dim = elem
      
    self.model = nn.ModuleList(self.autoencoders)
  
  def encode(self, x):
    enc = x
    for ae in self.model:
      enc = ae.encode(enc)
    return enc

  def decode(self, x):
    dec = x
    # reverse list of models and decode
    for ae in self.model[::-1]:
      dec = ae.decode(dec)
    return dec

  def forward(self, x):
    x = self.encode(x)
    x = self.decode(x)
    return x
```

Then I train the model using this, the encoded representation of the input is passed to the next autoencoder

```
data_in = X_train
hidden_layers = [512, 256, 128]
deep_ae = DeepAutoEncoder(X_train.shape[1], hidden_layers)
for ae in deep_ae.model:
  fit(2, ae, data_in)
  # create latent rappresentation of data
  # the new encoded data_in will be passed to the data loader in the fit method
  with torch.no_grad():
    data_in = ae.encode(data_in)
```

this is the fit and evaluate method. X_train is just the dataset without the labels

```
def evaluate_MSE(model, eval_dataset):
  with torch.no_grad():
    eval_output = model(eval_dataset)

    loss = F.mse_loss(eval_output, eval_dataset)
  
  return loss.item()

def fit(epochs, model, X_train):
  
  print(X_train.shape)
  # prepare data loaders
  train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(X_train, batch_size=20, shuffle=True)
  criterion = nn.MSELoss()
  optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

  history = []

  for epoch in range(1, epochs+1):
    model.train()

    for images in train_loader:
      # reset gradient
      optimizer.zero_grad()

      # add noise
      noisy_images = add_noise(images, 0, noise_std)

      #forward pass
      output = model(noisy_images)
      loss = criterion(output, images)

      # optimizer step and backward pass
      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()

    train_loss = evaluate_MSE(model, X_train)
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch} \tTraining Loss: {train_loss}')
    history.append(train_loss)
    
  return history
```

This Is what I obtain when I run the training, as you can see the loss is diverging, how can I solve?

```
torch.Size([60000, 784])
Epoch: 1    Training Loss: 0.027089910581707954
Epoch: 2    Training Loss: 0.010246861726045609
torch.Size([60000, 512])
Epoch: 1    Training Loss: 2.82458233833313
Epoch: 2    Training Loss: 3.0086123943328857
torch.Size([60000, 256])
Epoch: 1    Training Loss: 176.9993896484375
Epoch: 2    Training Loss: 207.57615661621094
```

Comment: To reiterate what mknull said in their answer, you should explain why you're calling `fit()` so many times and only running it for two epochs each time. Given that you have a reasonable answer to that question, then besides your learning rate, it could also just be that your model is relatively deep, yet it has nothing to prevent exploding / vanishing gradients. You'd usually want a combination between residual connections and some sort of normalization like batch norm (/ group norm / layer norm). If your representation size changes a lot, you might use U-net-style residual connections.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, lower your learning rate. Then clarify why there is a change in size every two epochs.